# Mongoose/mongodb find nearest match

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I am currently using mongoose, with this model instructions in model called tickets

Fromticket, Number default 0
Toticket, number, default 0

Let say I have these rows:

```
{fromticket:1 , toticket:3000},
fromticket:3001 , toticket:29000}
```

,

how can I find the row that contains for example the ticket is  20000? Or 3001? ( would be row number 2 in the example)

```
Tickets.find( row where owner is ticket 2000)
```

Comment: does latest toticket mean toticket with the maximum value? @maria

Comment: @RanojitBanerjee  yes, but my main issue is to find the row of 20000 issue :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each term in a query is implicitly ANDed, so you can query for the document where `fromticket <= 20000` and `toticket >= 20000` using:

```
var ticket = 20000;
Tickets.findOne({
    fromticket: {$lte: ticket},
    toticket: {$gte: ticket}
}, (err, ticket) => {...});
```

Comment: Will this return the 2000? Isn't this checking if it's lower than 20000 and higher than 20000? While I actually need the document that have it.

Comment: It will find the `{fromticket:3001 , toticket:29000}` document that spans ticket number 20,000 because the doc's `fromticket` value is less than 20000 and its `toticket` value is greater than 20000. It checks out when I try it.

Comment: What If the ticket was 3001? What Would happening then? Or 29000?

Comment: @maria The same (second) doc would be returned because `3001 <= 3001`.

Comment: Same with 29000?:) will Check tomorrow

Comment: Yeah @JohnnyHK  :) accepted it now. So you know node? I have one more question on stack overflow